# How to override the array?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am writing a game where a user has to input 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 50. These numbers are being saved in the array `intPlayersNumbers`. If the conditions are not met the user has to enter the numbers again. Why is the array `intPlayersNumbers` not being overwritten?  It is saving only the numbers that were entered for the 1st time.

```java
public class Game {

    int chosenNumbers = 5;
    int chosenNumber;
    String numbers;
    int[] raffleArray = new int[chosenNumbers];

    public void askForNumbers(){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        numbers = in.nextLine();
        String[] playersNumbers = (numbers.split(" "));
        int[] intPlayersNumbers = new int[playersNumbers.length];
        for(int a =0; a<playersNumbers.length; a++ ){
            intPlayersNumbers[a] = Integer.parseInt(playersNumbers[a]);
        }
        //checking the numbers
        checkTheNumbers(intPlayersNumbers);
    }

    public int[] checkTheNumbers(int[] intPlayersNumbers){

        //if there is 5 numbers
        if(intPlayersNumbers.length==5){
            //if the numbers are form 1 to 50
            for(int i = 0; i<intPlayersNumbers.length; i++){
                if(intPlayersNumbers[i]<50 && intPlayersNumbers[i]>0){
                    continue;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please enter 5 nums from 1 to 50.");
                    askForNumbers();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers");
            askForNumbers();
        }
return intPlayersNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you either use a debugger or add some print statements to see what is going on.

Comment: Why not just check each number and if the input is invalid ask the user to input it again rather than taking in all wrong values in the array and *then* manipulating it?

Comment: Also the context of this code is missing (main method etc.).

Comment: If the numbers aren't accepted, you make a call back to `askForNumbers` - but once that is done (which doesn't return anything), you return the original numbers with `return intPlayersNumbers;`. Either store these externally or return appropriately.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you can easily solve this using recursion. Since the context of your question is not completely clear i did one or two assumptions. If you want a slightly different solution you can use the comments as hints.

```java
public void askForNumbers() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // use the sout before the system.in waits for you first input
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 nums from 1 to 50.");
    numbers = in.nextLine();
    String[] playersNumbers = (numbers.split(" "));
    int[] intPlayersNumbers = new int[playersNumbers.length];
    // check if the array has lenght 5 directly after the split.
    if (intPlayersNumbers.length != 5) { // if the split.length != 5 start over
      askForNumbers();
    }
    else {
      for (int a = 0; a < playersNumbers.length; a++) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(playersNumbers[a]); //beware this can cause a numberFormatException !!!
        if (i > 0 && i < 51) {  // if one of the number is not in range start over. 
          intPlayersNumbers[a] = i;
        }
        else {
          System.out.printf("%d was not between 0 and 50", i); // print which integer was the culprit
          askForNumbers();
          return; //return so this method ends here; 
          }
      }
      raffleArray = intPlayersNumbers; // or return intPlayersNumbers , you will have to change the return type of the method as well
    }
  }
```

I you have any questions about this solution, just leave a comment.

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of recursion.

Comment: I agree with @rghome. You should consider using `while` loop to handle user input instead of recursion. In this case, I think you're creating a stack of calls that will never be used. It's usually not a good sign to have a recursive method with no return and which not using any "external" resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think a do-while makes more sense here. Additionally, I think it makes more sense that `checkTheNumbers` returns a `boolean` as it performs a validation. The solution below will continuously ask for numbers until `checkTheNumbers` returns `true`.

```
public int[] askForNumbers(){
    int[] intPlayersNumbers;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 nums from 1 to 50.");
        numbers = in.nextLine();
        String[] playersNumbers = (numbers.split(" "));
        intPlayersNumbers = new int[playersNumbers.length];
        for(int a =0; a<playersNumbers.length; a++ ){
            intPlayersNumbers[a] = Integer.parseInt(playersNumbers[a]);
        }
    } while (!checkTheNumbers(intPlayersNumbers));
    return intPlayersNumbers;
}

public boolean checkTheNumbers(int[] intPlayersNumbers) {
    if(intPlayersNumbers.length==5) {
        for(int i = 0; i < intPlayersNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (intPlayersNumbers[i] > 50 || intPlayersNumbers[i] <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter 5 nums from 1 to 50.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```